# How to create image of native OS

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I want to transfer working environment of this OS to other computers by making image of it.
so this image can be run in Virtual machine on those computer. 
I wanted to know how to make .vdi or .vmdk of ubuntu12.04 OS ??

please help
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use remastersys ... Its there in repository .. Tried and tested method ..

Comment: this will give you an iso image with all current softwares bundled .. you can use the image in virtual-box or something ..

Comment: Keep in mind that remastersys has a 4GB iso file size limit. If your system takes up more space than that, the iso file won't be created